# How to set Math text size & line spacing

Tags: front-end, fonts

I have chosen different font for text. Unfortunately this font is larger than the standard Times font. So all math symbols (e.g. greek) are now a little too small. If I could just set the FontSize for the math font to 13 it would probably look good. How do I accomplish that?

If it is not that simple:
In defining a custom Style via Stylesheet (or private Style Definitions), what is the correct way to define a custom size for the math font. There are Style definitions for "Display Formula" and "Inline Formula", but if I type just an inline cell, the latter does not apply.

Comment: Have you tried increasing the font size in style InlineFormula?

Comment: Yep, but `InlineFormula` is different from `InlineCell`

Comment: There is, in fact, a style definition called `InlineCell` which affects all inline cells. But change with care...this affects inline cells everywhere. The style definitions in Core.nb for inline cells are very conservative for that reason. In general, there is no way to pick out just the characters in the Mathematica* fonts and resize them. I suppose one could come up with some hacky post-processing of a notebook which would selectively apply styles, but aside from that, it just can't be done.